# where command not found os x

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

Okay so the title is pretty self explanitory, when I type `where ...` as a command it returns

```
-bash: where: command not found
```

my current bash profile includes :

```
export PATH="/usr/local/lib:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bin:$PATH"
```

I googled it for a while and found that most people just need `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` which I have both of.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23):

"where" is a shell builtin for csh.  Is that what you're really looking for?

"which" and "whereis" are under /usr/bin, and tell you where to find a given command.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm looking for, it's interesting that I can't find it with /usr/bin in my $PATH

Answer (score 12):

As Stuart says, `where` is a tcsh builtin command.  It's an extended version of the `which` command; `which` tells you what a command name resolves to, and `where` shows a list of all the places (including aliases, builtins, and executables in `$PATH`) where a command might be found.

The bash equivalent is `type -a`.

If you like, you can add this function definition to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
where() { type -a "$@" ; }
```

The output isn't in exactly the same format, but it gives you the same information.

(Or you might consider just re-training yourself to use `type -a` rather than `where`.)