# Mac Shell .sh Command not possible

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sh

Is it possible to execute `where` inside a .sh Shell Script on Mac ?

If I execute `where` in the Terminal the command exist and works.

If I execute `where` inside a .sh File I get the Error: `./TestInternal.sh: line 16: where: command not found`.

How could I fix / understand that ?

Comment: `where` is a zsh-ism. What to use instead depends on which shell your script uses.

Comment: Is it `#!/bin/sh`? `#!/usr/bin/env bash`? Something else?

Comment: (btw, `.sh` is not a particularly useful description of a file type -- unfortunately, many people put `.sh` as an extension on _all_ scripts, no matter what the interpreter is; thus, `.sh` extensions are found on not just POSIX sh scripts, but also bash scripts, zsh scripts, ksh scripts, and many others; there's no knowing what interpreter will be used if all you have is the file extension: you need to check the shebang line)

Answer (score -1):

I found out that `where` is an extended version of `which`. If I use `which` inside the .sh Script it works.

Source: [where command not found os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263967/where-command-not-found-os-x)

Comment: **NO**. `which` is an external command, not a shell builtin. It has no access to the shell's set of defined functions, aliases, PATH cache, etc -- and it's also slow to run (since it needs to start up a separate executable). If your shell is `bash` you may want `type`, or if it's `sh` you may want `command -v`. `which` is almost always the wrong thing.

Comment: Then it seems the Answer from Keith can be improved.

Comment: The answer from Keith _does_ discuss `type -a`, and indeed describes it as "the bash equivalent".

Comment: I tried `type` inside th .sh Script and it seems not to work. Possibly the syntax with `type` is different to the syntax of `which`.

Comment: Once again: **which interpreter does your shell use?** Without knowing what kind of script it is, I can't tell you what the correct usage is (you're right that `type` does have syntax that `which` does not).

Comment: ...however, the most portable approach (the approach that will work on all POSIX-family shells, and even some non-POSIX shells like zsh) is `command -v`, as in, replacing `which something` with `command -v something`. `command -v` is built into all standard-compliant shells, whereas `which` only works if your operating system provides an executable for it (or if you're using a shell that adds it as a builtin, but many -- including bash, ash, and dash -- do not).

Comment: I use `zsh` and that I try
`if command -v pyenv == "pyenv not found"; then; brew install pyenv; fi`

Comment: BTW, if you're doing something like `curl=$(which curl)` and then later using `$curl`, it's better to just skip that altogether and just run `curl` in your later code. The shell caches PATH lookups itself; there's _never_ (at least, in the last 30 years or so) been a good reason to write code like that, other than seeing code written by other people who also didn't have a good reason (see: cargo-cult programing).

Comment: `command -v pyenv >/dev/null 2>&1 || brew install pyenv` should work everywhere -- sh, zsh, bash, ksh, etc. Or if you actually want the error message printed, just `command -v pyenv || brew install pyenv`.

Comment: Nice but thats not working in the opposite Case - if pyenv is installed it tries to reinstall pyenv.

Comment: It would be `&&` for the opposite case. `||` proceeds only if `command -v` fails.

Comment: Was thinking that but it seems to execute in any case.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `command -v foobar || echo "could not find foobar"` prints "could not find foobar", whereas `command -v ls || echo "could not find ls"` does not print "could not find ls".

Comment: Thats true. But inside a .sh file it behaves different.

Comment: Again: Cannot reproduce. I wouldn't be surprised if your script had hidden/nonprintable characters.

Comment: What does `bash -x yourscript.sh` log?

Comment: (and once again -- though I do tire of repeating myself -- "a .sh file" isn't a collection of words that actually _means anything_; a .sh file can be _any_ kind of file; you could even have a file with .sh in its name that's actually a Python script or a compiled C executable; it's the shebang line at the top of a file that tells the operating system how to execute a script; or the magic bytes indicating the binary type if it's a binary rather than a script -- a .sh file that starts with `#!/bin/bash` will behave very differently from a .sh file that starts with `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`, etc).

Comment: Totally agree! No need to repeat yourself, but thanks.I created a new file and there it works. `bash -x..` shows:

+ uname
+ '[' Darwin == Darwin ']'
+ os=mac
+ prefix=
+ '[' mac == mac ']'
++ type brew
+ '[' 'brew is /usr/local/bin/brew' == 'brew not found' ']'
+ command -v pyenv
+ command -v pyenv == 'pyenv not found'
....

Comment: I found the Issue. Inside the .sh File was an `if` without `[ ]` and this caused the `command -v..` command to behave different.