# how can i uninstall cmake 3.2.3 or how can i found the directory of cmake ...thank you

Tags: cmake

```
(fbxpose) poseing@DESKTOP-0Q1RIBJ:~/blender-git/blender$ make bpy

Configuring Blender in "/home/poseing/blender-git/build_linux_bpy" ...
loading initial cache file /home/poseing/blender-git/blender/build_files/cmake/config/bpy_module.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.10 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.2.3


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
GNUmakefile:340: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: I think you really wanted to ask about *updating* cmake. See [tour] and [ask].

Comment: I think that this error isn't correct... 3.10>3.2.3??????

Comment: 3.10(.0) is definitely greater than 3.2.anything, as 10 > 2. (3.10 is not 3.1.0.)

Comment: oh,,thanks nice point

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942713/how-do-i-remove-cmake-after-installing-it-from-source) is some information about uninstall cmake on Linux machine.

To find cmake location, run below command:

```
where cmake
```

Comment: when in uninstall cmake it uninstalls another version....not the 3.2.3 one....so how can I find the right directory of cmake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263967/where-command-not-found-os-x
how about "which" command?